# How do I enable inline field editing in SiteEdit working when using an XSLT TBB for simple field

Tags: tridion

I got answer from the SDL Tridion forum that we can enable inline editing for embedded schema "paragraph" that has "text" field in it.

It would be verty helpful if someone helps me to enable it for simple field.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='paragraph']">
            <div>
                <tcdl:ComponentField name="paragraph[{position() -1}].text" index="0">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[local-name()='text']"/>
                </tcdl:ComponentField>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This code loops through each embedded paragraph field, outputs the text field's value and wraps it with the appropriate SiteEdit TCDL syntax.

I am using Tridion 2011 SP1 and the XSLT mediator from SDLTridionworld.com.

Say my component has a field named "pageHeader". How can we enable inline editing in XSLT TBB.

Comment: By now you should be getting used to these questions: what Tridion version are you using? And how are you processing this XSLT? I assume the asnwer is Tridion 2011 and that you are still using the XSLT Mediator from SDL Tridion World. If that is the case, please update you question and remember to add these details next time.

Comment: Thank you..I will follow these steps for the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head I think the following should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='pageHeader']">
            <div>
                <tcdl:ComponentField name="pageHeader[{position() -1}]" index="0">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </tcdl:ComponentField>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or if it is a single value field:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <h1>
                <tcdl:ComponentField name="pageHeader" index="0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='pageHeader'"/>
                </tcdl:ComponentField>
        </h1>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```